# how to functional test sites with knp_pagination_sortable()?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

How to functional test sites with knp_pagination_sortable() ?

```
<th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(foo) }}</th>
```

In browser same url got different content than in functional test.

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/ksiazka/?sort=a.wydawnictwo&direction=asc&page=1');
$this->assertGreaterThan(1, $crawler->filter('a:contains("ill")')->count());
//Failed asserting that 1 is greater than 1.
```

[image]

The issue was also pointed out [there](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/issues/374) with a clue:

> - underlying paging library (knp-components) is independent to Symfony's Request/Response system and extracts $_GET parameters
>     directly
> - Symfony's functional tests aren't actually making a real HTTP request, they are simply constructing a Request object and passing it
>     through the application.

Comment: same fixtures? try dumping the request content and check for the highlighted data

Comment: no solution, not solved. leave it. edited main post with quotation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are testing absolute address with variables in there and the  controller not receive any of this.

Probably knp paginator component generate sortable url. Try generate an url in the test with the knp-paginator component or check better the url you are testing

Comment: ..also I made mistake saying the controller not receive query params (I used to think than controller have to have {slugs_in_route_annotation}), but it receive by Request argument in controller. (Ignore my comments, I am thinking aloud, will remove comments soon.)